# Can maintainers see my activity on Gitlab? Which roles are able to do this?

Tags: security, gitlab, roles, repo

I recently had been working on a project on Gitlab and I noticed I can keep track of what's been going on (such as times for commits and pushes, the deleting and creating of branches and repos) via the activity tab which shows every changes along with their times and I had assigned others in my group maintainer roles for this project.

[image]

My question is can these maintainers see my activity just like I do or is the permission for maintainers just limited to looking at repositories and commits and nothing more? Is this question justified?